# Importing GraphStream library in NetBeans 8.0

Tags: java, netbeans, import, graphstream

I am just getting started with GraphStream and using NetBeans as an IDE in my laptop (Yosemite 10.10). I already downloaded and included .jar library file into my project:

[image: Libraries: gs-algo-1.3.zip; gs-core-1.3.zip; gs-ui-1.3.zip; JDK 1.7 (Default)]

My problem is I still can’t import `graphstream` in my class. This is what I wrote:

```
import org.graphstream.graph.*;
```

but I’m still getting the error message

> Package import org.graphstream.graph.* doesn’t exist

Is there any way to import GraphStream in my NetBeans? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to extract those 3 `gs-*.zip` files that you downloaded from the website. Then, inside the extracted folders you will find `gs-*.jar` files. These are the actual binaries that Netbeans needs as dependencies.

Comment: Oh god, I forgot to extract those library. Thank you so much, Yoann